How to disable TLSv1.2 in my CENTOS based system

I want to disable TLSv1.2 in my centOS based RHEL system. I don't have a lot of knowledge of server management or security protocols, but the VAPT report says that we need to close TLSv1.2.
i have two files to modify, httpd.conf and ssl.conf, both of which has SSLProtocol in them. For reference , i have pasted here.
SSL.conf:
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
SSLProxyCipherSuite PROFILE=SYSTEM
</VirtualHost>

httpd.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName XYZZZ.in
SSLEngine On
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
Header always set Permissions-Policy "interest-cohort=()"
Redirect permanent / XYZ.in
</VirtualHost>

The above mentioned code is still not helping. TLSv1.2 is still enabled. I am using sslscan.exe to check. Please help if you know the solution.

What kind of security report is this, which classifies TLS 1.2 as insecure? Looks for me like a bogus information. The report also claims that BEAST attack is possible against TLS 1.2, which is clearly wrong  since this affects only TLS 1.0 and lower - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#BEAST_attack

what is sslscan.exe? Is it the windows port of sslscan that hasn't been updated in 15 years?

I've not checked real-life access statistics in a bit, but I'm not sure I'd disable TLSv1.2 if my audience included, say, a four-year-old smartphone. That being said, I find the mozilla TLS generator suggestions to be a good starting point.

Probably not the reason but you did not say you restarted applications after updating the files.  You'll need to recycle Apache (httpd) or wait for next time server is rebooted.

@SteffenUllrich: and not even 1.0 is vulnerable to BEAST since 2012 when everybody (and their dog) implemented first-block-split (although 1.0 and 1.1 still have CBC/Lucky13)

Actually I did restart the server. It still doesn't work. Is there someplace else the SSLprotocol configuration might be at?

TLS 1.2 is not deprecated by any major players that I know of.  Based on over half a million log records, for web the current breakdown is 80/20 (1.3/1.2) and for email it is 75/25.  So if you disallow 1.2 you will cut off a quarter to a fifth of the world.
You can check TLS versions at https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver.  For web, open the More Options and change the port to 443 (HTTPS).

The statistics you provide are about the server side - which is irrelevant for the question. Instead the capabilities of the client side are relevant, i.e. will the client support TLS 1.3 or will the client fail if TLS 1.3 is the only protocol supported by the server is TLS 1.3. Apart from that it does not even address what the OP is asking - which is about HOW to disable TLS 1.2 not if this is a wise choice (which likely isn't). So any statistics would be more appropriate as a comment - but even in this case please use statistics about client support not server support.

Steffen, I'm confused. The config files the OP posted are for Apache webserver and the question was about disabling TLS1.2 therein. The statistics I posted are for the past four days from an Apache webserver.

You cannot claim by looking at other server configurations that "you will cut off a quarter to a fifth of the world". These servers don't connect to servers, clients will instead. An in order to determine how much clients will be cut off one need to look at capabilities of web browsers and potential other clients. And at least all common web browsers support TLS 1.3 for years, so they will not be affected at all.

Thanks for your view Steve. Though, I am skeptical they will even listen to my reasoning even, still, I will try to convince them. However, in long run my only option will be to shut off TLSv1.2. so if anyone can help a little bit about why is 1.2 not being shut down, it'll be very helpful as I can submit the report from my side.

Sayak, I would try "SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.3".  There are other posters that have had problems disabling TLSv1.2.  They suggest limiting Apache to only TLSv1.3 ciphers.

Steve, do I need to mandatorily change the ciphers along with the protocols on order to TLS being disabled? Is that the reason my solution isn't working

Sayak ---
I just tested an Apache server and "SSLProtocol TLSv1.3" (no all, no plus, no minus) would not allow a connection with TLSv1.2.
However some other posts have said that they could not disable 1.2 so if that does not work for you, then try limiting Apache to just TLS1.3 ciphers (SSLCipherSuite).

Do you think the ssl certificates may contain any information about using TLSv1.2? nothing works as of now , i do not know what to do.

I don't think that's possible.  I wonder if you are changing the wrong config file.  Put a syntax error in the file (misspell SSLProtocol?) and see if Apache notices.
